# C counting allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management

I have to make a program that would allocate an array of `int` with `mmap()` and then count how much memory was actually allocated to it.

So far I have the code that allocates the array, but I don't know how to count the allocated memory. This is what I tried so far:

the handler:

```
 int i;
void segfault_sigaction(int signal, siginfo_t *si, void *arg)
{
    printf("ujel segafult, velikost pomnilnika je: %d bajtov\n", sizeof(int) * i);
    exit(0);
}
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *addr;  
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa,0,sizeof(sigaction));
    sa.sa_handler = segfault_sigaction;
    //sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    //sa.sa_sigaction = segfault_sigaction;
    //sa.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGSEGV,&sa, NULL);

    addr = mmap(NULL, n * sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ ,MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,-1,0);
    i = n;

    while(1){

        addr[i+1] = 5;
        i++;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: after reading your answers and the task description again I changed the code, I put in a handler that catches SEGFAULT, but it is not really reliable(sometimes it works, sometimes the default segmentation fault error occurs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amount of memory mapped by `mmap()` is just what you requested, perhaps rounded up a bit.  If you're asking, "How can I see how much it rounded up," the answer is you can't do so in a general way, but some specific platforms may have APIs that let you figure it out.  But there's no reason why you'd need to.

The code you've written seems to be "searching" for the end of the allocation by looking for a nonzero part.  This results in undefined behavior because you will always run off the end of the allocation.  You absolutely must not do this.  Just use the size that you passed to `mmap()` as the size.  That's the only size that matters.

Comment: Certainly, not using `sizeof` which appears in the code.

Comment: I have to count all the memory allocated to the program, as far as I can tell from the task description. It says  should do so by moving past the final element of the array and continue on until I get a SEGFAULT error.

Comment: @TimPungračič That's not reliable: there could be some other mapping (e.g. the program code) immediately after it. Most platforms give a way to analyze a program's memory mappings, but it's OS-dependent, e.g. parsing `/proc/self/maps` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, but sadly that is what the task expects of me. Allocate an array of ints and then check and output the amount of memory allocated to the whole program.

Comment: @TimPungračič Note "Check and output the amount of memory allocated to the whole program" and "count the allocated memory" as in the question are two entirely different things. The former can only be done by using system-specific functions. Have a look at `mallinfo()`

Comment: Thank you for that answer, will definitely take a look at mallinfo(), though the task does say that I should do this by moving past the last element of the allocated array and check the cells until I get a SEGFAULT error.

Comment: @TimPungračič In this case, your task is a "might probably work under circumstances" task, unfortunately. As pointed out above, in case the system decides to place some readable memory (shared lib mapping space, for example) adjacent to your allocated area, you will end up with a wrong reading.

Comment: I guess that is alright though, since it is only a task for college meant to teach us how to work with memory.